# Laravel 4: No hint path defined

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to do package route and this is my working example:

```
Route::get('pack', function()
{
    return View::make('MyPackage::test');
});
```

When I run the website, I got this error: `No hint path defined for [MyPackage]`. How can I solve it? How can I define the path?

Thank you.

Comment: may be typo with MyPackage.

Answer (score 1):

That is the syntax for showing a view that's not in the main views folder.

Try adding a hint. Look at http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-configuration under 'Registering A Resource Namespace Manually' and add a hint called 'MyPackage' and then the path to your views folder.